# Is this construction common in formal English?

Tags: writing-style

Are *any* and *very* commonly used together in formal English, as in the sentence below, and does them coming together denote poor style?

> There aren't any very old buildings in this city.

Comment: No. Please look up *ancient* in a dictionary.

Comment: My great grandfather is very old, not ancient.

Comment: 'very old' is fine. Depends on how old. 'Ancient' is much older than 'very old'

Comment: @Kris: I don't see what you mean. Are you suggesting [*very ancient*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22very+ancient%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) isn't a valid usage (for the same reason some people might object to *very unique*, for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences are suitable in formal writing but they have very different meanings. Ancient buildings may imply buildings that are thousands, or at least several hundreds, of years old while 'very old' might refer to a build that was built as recently as around a century or so ago. Especially in the context of architecture, ancient is an adjective which describes a greater magnitude of age than the phrase 'very old' would. You should select the sentence based on the meaning you are attempting to convey.

Just as a side note: The adjective 'very' is often used heavily in poor writing and so some people might find it less than appealing in certain contexts. This is more of a stylistic preference that often shows up in heavily edited academic or literary writing and less of a set 'rule' but that might be the source of your confusion.

Comment: The construction "any very old" sounds ill-formed to my non-native ears, I'm trying to know why before bringing myself to get used to it.

Comment: I see, it's probably that the combination of any and very sounds a little sing-songy because of the rhyme. Perhaps you'd like to try something like "There are no very old buildings in this city." or "This city has no very old buildings."

Comment: Ancient has different semantics in different contexts; some people would only use it in this context to refer to a building that pre-dates the medieval period (such as the Pyramids or the Pantheon). That said, "there aren't any very old buildings" sounds quite awkward; I'd go with "None of the buildings in this city are very old."

Comment: “Substitute *damn* every time you’re inclined to write *very*; your  editor will delete it and the writing will be just as it should be.” ―Mark Twain